# Search a value in column and give the value from another

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database called Process It has 22 columns

- Column 1 is Id which serial and primary,
- Column 2 Process name  Character(50)
- column 3 is "Amount 1"  Character Varying
- Column 4 is "Time 1" is integer.

[image]

The rest of the columns are the same as 3 & 4 but going up in number ie column 5 "Amount 2", column 6 is "Time 2".

What i need is a query which looks in the amount columns for normal and then display the ID and the Time column. for example:

Process Table

```
ID .  Process Name .    Amount 1 .  Time 1 .   Amount 2   Time 2

1 .       Pick     .     normal .     20 .       normal .   40
2 .       Pack     .     normal .     40 .          3 .     10
3 .       Pull     .       3 .        20 .          1 .     60
4 .       Play     .     normal .     40
```

Result

```
ID .       Time 1 .       Time 2    
1 .         20 .            40    
2 .         40    
4 .         40
```

I have tried the following codes :

```
select public."Process", amount_1 from
names-# (select ID,time_1 FROM public."Process" AS normal_tasks);

select public."Process", amount_1 from
names-# select id, Time_1 from public."Process" where Amount_1!='normal';
```

but i'm getting syntax errors.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks

Dave

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Right now the logic isnt clear, lot of querys can give you that desire result. Please format the queries to be more readeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `CASE`

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN Amount_1 = 'Normal' 
             THEN Time1
        END as Time1,
        CASE WHEN Amount_2 = 'Normal' 
             THEN Time2
        END as Time2
 FROM Process
 WHERE 'Normal' IN (Amount_1, Amount_2)
```

You have to add one for each of those 22 columns

Comment: Hello Juan    I have tried the code, but i am getting this syntax error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 7: FROM public."Process"   i was getting the same with process typed in public."Process" is the schema which the table is in and all other queries i have used needed that code to use the table. Can you help me with what i am doing wrong?

Comment: As I said on the previous comment Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output.  Also show us the exact query giving you the error. Right now your query has some sintaxis error and you havent fix it after I formated